# What is the best approach to reduce size of apk by storing resources on the Internet?

Tags: android

I have a ringtone application on Google Market which is close to 12Mo in size.  I would had more ringtones into it but it will obviously increase the APK size. Actually, the ringtones are MP3 that are in the res/raw folder of my application.

How can I reduce the size of my APK by not storing the sound files (MP3) inside the APK but instead fetching them on the Internet the first time they are requested (and playing locally the subsequent times)?

Is there a best practice, an Android design pattern or library that I can use to help?

Comment: UPDATE: My ringtones were previously MP3 at 320Kbps totalizing 16.5MB. Now they are AAC at 128Kbps totalizing 7.2MB. The audio quality is still very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downloading ringtones from net is not a bad idea for reducing apk as long as the user doesn't mind it. So you can use it. Besides that you can also consider using AAC instead of mp3. AAC achieves better compression at a given quality, compared to mp3.

you can check this [article](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-To-Reduce-APK-File-Size-in-Android) to know about different techniques of reducing apk size

Comment: I converted my ringtones to AAC with a bitrate of 128Kb/s and sucessfully reduce the size of my application. Thanks for the link, it was very helpful.